# jquery slider under navbar useing fixed position

Tags: jquery, css, nav

Im trying to create a slider under the main navigation bar so when a user put there mouse over a main item the slider follows there mouse, I have this working for the most part but when i scroll out the menu-slide does not stay under the menu items. 
This is because of the fixed positioning but im unable to get this to work without the fixed positoning... really stuck

Here is my code css first

```
#navbar {
position: relative;
width: 980px;
height: 29px;
}
/* MENU SLIDER */
/*#slider-container{ position: relative;}*/
#slider-container {
height: 5px;
width: 980px;
position: relative;
}
#menu-slide {
height: 4px;
width: 52px;
background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/glowbg.png) no-repeat;
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 1px;
z-index: -5;
position: fixed;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Now the rest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bretts Gaming</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro"> 
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/superfish.css" media="screen">
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="./css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/superfish2.css" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/go.fullBg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var left = $('.first').offset().left + ($('.first').width() / 2 - 15 );
        $('#menu-slide').stop().animate( {left: left  }, 400 );
    $('li').mouseover( function() { 
        var left = $(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2 - 20 );
        $('#menu-slide').stop().animate( {left: left  }, 400 );
    });
    $('li').mouseleave(function(){
         var left = $('.first').offset().left + ($('.first').width() / 2 - 20);
         $('#menu-slide').stop().animate( {left: left  }, 400 );
    }); 
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>     
 <div id="topnav">                    
            <ul id="navbar"class="sf-menu">
                <li class="current first"><a href="#a">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CORPORATE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CRUSING</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LEISURE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GROUPS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VIRTUOSO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="slider-container">
                <div id="menu-slide"></div>
            </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would great

Thank you

Comment: no need to use fixed position, give your detail code, i'll fix it.